# NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves option is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key": @"value"};
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data  
    options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
NSMutableString *ms =  [dict1 objectForKey:@"key"];
ms.string = @"ss";
```

I got an exception from the code above

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString:'

What's the problem ?

Comment: Don't you think the "attempt to mutate immutable object" refers to the
`NSMutableString ms` object ?

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag It does. But it shouldn't, since it's supposed to be mutable.

Comment: At least, change the question name. `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` isn't the problem!

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag It most likely is.

Comment: I tried running the code. It works perfectly. The last line is the problem.

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag Weird. I also tried running it and it threw me the exact same exception.

Comment: Here's the output for `NSLog(@"%@ : %@",[dict1 allKeys], [dict1 allValues]);` :                                                                     

`(key) : (value)`

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag And how is that helpful? I have logged the class of the value and it is `___NSCFConstantString` whereas it's supposed to be `NSMutableString` or one of its private concrete subclasses...

Comment: Here's the output for : `NSMutableString *ms = [dict1 objectForKey:@"key"];
     NSLog(@"%@",ms);`

`value`

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag Yay. And it's still immutable, while it should be mutable.

Comment: `ms.string` - The description of that method as given by Apple is "Returns an empty string".

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag You really don't get the point... (and that comment is wrong anyway. What OP is talking about is an instance method, it's not the class method that you're confusing it with.)

Comment: Well, if I am so wrong - what's your brilliant solution ?

Comment: This really looks like a bug in NSJSONSerialization and should be reported to Apple. The problem is also mentioned here https://github.com/mattt/AnyJSON : *"NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves is not supported (it doesn't even work with NSJSONSerialization on iOS 5+)"*

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag I have no solution. It shouldn't work like this. As Martin R pointed out above, this seems like a bug. No need to be condescending -- you were wrong and I pointed it out.

Comment: You're right. I just discovered the same problem in my app (ironical isn't it ?). My sincere apologies - @H2CO3.

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag No problem. Yes, this indeed seems a bug. (I suggest you see one of Douglas Crockford's JavaScript videos. He explains how he found a bug in his own jsonlint tool after refusing to warn about that mistake :P)

Comment: Yea, my entire conversation seems so stupid now! Well, live and learn. Well, thanks for telling me. Its crucial in my app! Thanks to @MartinR  and you!

Answer (score 0):

I've just been confronted with this problem, it's annoying indeed.

I've developed a workaround with two additions on `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary` which parse the entire JSON tree and replace each leaf occurrence with its mutable relative (if it conforms the `NSMutableCopying` protocol).

Here's the implementation:

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (mutableLeavesAddition)

- (void)setLeavesMutable {
    for (int i=0; i<[self count]; i++) {
        NSObject *element = self[i];
        if ([element isKindOfClass:NSMutableDictionary.class] || [element isKindOfClass:NSMutableArray.class]) {
            [(NSMutableDictionary*)element setLeavesMutable];
        } else if ([element.class conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSMutableCopying)]) {
            self[i] = [element mutableCopy];
        }
    }
}

@end

@implementation NSMutableDictionary (mutableLeavesAddition)

- (void)setLeavesMutable {
    for (NSString *key in [self allKeys]) {
        NSObject *element = self[key];
        if ([element isKindOfClass:NSMutableDictionary.class] || [element isKindOfClass:NSMutableArray.class]) {
            [(NSMutableDictionary*)element setLeavesMutable];
        } else if ([element.class conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSMutableCopying)]) {
            self[key] = [element mutableCopy];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Note: it only works if you chosen `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` during the JSON parsing.